# Is there a more Mathematica-y way to label these plots?

Tags: plotting, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, hold

I am studying an infinite square well in the context of quantum mechanics.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

(* Length of the well *)
L = 1;

(* The eigenfunctions, n=1,2,3,... *)
u[n_, x_] := Sqrt[2/L] Sin[n π x / L]

(* Probability density function, ρ[x] = |u[n,x]|^2 *)
ρ[n_, x_] := Simplify[u[n, x]\[Conjugate] u[n, x], {n ∈ Integers, x ∈ Reals}]

(* Plots of ρ[n,x] for various values of n *)
Table[ Plot[ρ[n, x], {x, 0, L}, PlotLabel -> "ρ[" <> ToString@n <> ",x]"], {n, 1, 4}]
```

And here is the output:

[image]

**My questions is**:

Can I use Mathematica pattern magic to rewrite `PlotLabel -> "ρ[" <> ToString@n <> ",x]"` ?

For instance, I tried (although I knew it wouldn't work): `PlotLabel -> HoldForm@ρ[n,x]`, but that of course leaves `n` unevaluated as well, although I would like `n` to be evaluated and then the result to be held.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your original method is fine, but perhaps this will be more to your liking:

```
Table[With[{n = ni},
  Plot[ρ[n, x], {x, 0, L}, PlotLabel -> Defer@ρ[n, x]]
  ], {ni, 1, 4}]
```

---

Another, perhaps less fundamental way is

```
Table[
    Plot[ρ[n, x], {x, 0, L}, PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", Top]]
 ,{n, 1, 4}]
```

[image: Example image]

Comment: Would be ok to use `HoldForm[]` instead of `Defer[]` here ? I tried it and it works, but are there any caveats?

Comment: @Zet Yes, of course, `HoldForm` is probably even safer as `Defer` gets evaluated when given explicitly as input.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably more Mathematica-ish. But sincerely, I would go with your solution :D

```
Table[Plot[ReleaseHold@# /. n -> r, {x, 0, L}, 
           PlotLabel -> (# /. n -> r)] &@HoldForm[ρ[n, x]], {r, 1, 4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Next time I will be very careful on what I'm wishing :P Thanks for the link and the solution !

Comment: I don't understand the Belisarius Superfluous Comma trick. It produces an error on my machine...

Comment: @cormullion Thanks, I did _several_ mistakes in the previous version. It worked here, but probably only because some dirty previous definitions or a simple copy-paste error.

Comment: @belisarius Damn, I thought I had spotted another devious trick...

Comment: @cormullion What you've spotted is called _stupidity_ by the locals here

Answer (score 4):

I'm always a fan of making a new function for plotting any time I'm going to do the same type of plot multiple times.

```
\[Rho]plot[n_, plotopts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Plot[\[Rho][n, x], {x, 0, L}, 
  Evaluate[FilterRules[{plotopts}, Options[Plot]]], 
  PlotLabel -> "\[Rho][" <> IntegerString[n] <> ",x]"]
```

Now you can do a simple plot like

```
\[Rho]plot[1]
```

and get

[image]

or you can add any options to it to fancy it up:

```
Grid[Partition[
  Table[\[Rho]plot[n, ImageSize -> 400, BaseStyle -> 20, 
    Frame -> True], {n, 4}]
  , 2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To my simple mind all the approaches suggested so far are overkill. I would do it the simple way -- I would use `Row`.

```
Table[Plot[\[Rho][n, x], {x, 0, L},
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"ρ[", n, ",\[ThinSpace]x]"}]], {n, 1, 4}]
```

Please take note of the use of a thin-space glyph. It is needed to make the spacing look right.

[image: plots.png]