# Calculate integral for arbitrary parameter n in infinite square well problem

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm continuing[[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35523/is-there-a-more-mathematica-y-way-to-label-these-plots),[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35642/why-does-fouriertransform-converge-while-same-integral-manually-written-does-n)] the study of an infinite square well in the context of quantum mechanics.

Ultimate goal is to calculate the product $\Delta x\Delta k$, for various eigenstates, that is for various values of number $n$. I have finished with $\Delta x$, but I'm stuck with $\Delta k$.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
(* The length of the well *)
L = 1;

(* The eigenfunctions, n=1,2,3,... *)
u[n_, x_] := If[x <= 0 || x >= L, 0, Sqrt[2/L] Sin[n π x / L]]

(* The Fourier transform of eigenfunctions u[n,x] from the position
   domain onto the momentum domain *)
φ[n_, k_] :=
    Simplify[
        FourierTransform[u[n, x], x, k, FourierParameters -> {0, -1}],
        n ∈ Integers]

(* The probability density function η(n,k) *)
η[n_, k_] := 
    FullSimplify[φ[n, k] \[Conjugate] φ[n, k],
    {n ∈ Integers, k ∈ Reals}]

(* Calculate (Δk)^2 = <k^2> - <k>^2 = <k^2> *)
Integrate[
    k^2 η[n, k], {k, -∞, +∞},
    (* Edited: Was: {n ∈ Integers, n > 0}, but this edit didn't
       fix the problem. *) 
    Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers && n > 0]
```

The problem is that *Mathematica* can't calculate the last integral for any arbitrary $n$, although it can, correctly, calculate its value for hardcoded $n$s. Like $n=1,2,...$.

**My question is**:
Do you have any idea on how I could calculate it, perhaps by rewriting it a bit, or by using some other trick? In case it helps, the result should be $n^2\pi^2$.

**Note**: Actually it can be calculated with Cauchy's residue theorem, but I'd like to avoid taking that route, if possible. Though, if it can't be done otherwise, I will post a solution with residual calculation so that this question has an answer.

**Mathematica.SE related (to the physical problem) questions**:

[Is there a more mathematica-y way to label these plots?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35523/is-there-a-more-mathematica-y-way-to-label-these-plots)

[Why does FourierTransform converge while same integral manually written does not?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35642/why-does-fouriertransform-converge-while-same-integral-manually-written-does-n)

Comment: There are no close votes, but you might find helpful a related post: [How do I evaluate a symbolic integral involving Hermite polynomials?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34440/how-do-i-evaluate-a-symbolic-integral-involving-hermite-polynomials).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code yields the correct result:

[image]

Another interesting fact is that if I omit the assumption that `k ∈ Reals`, then *Mathematica* still gets it right, but it takes ~3x more time:

[image]

What is puzzling though is that if I use `Assumptions` with `Integrate` I don't get the expected result:

[image]

I was under the impression that `Assuming[{a1,a2,...}, Integrate[...]]` was equivalent to `Integrate[..., Assumptions -> a1 && a2 && ...]`.

Could anyone please try to reproduce my results, ideally in a different OS/Mathematica version combination ? That is something other than *Mathematica* 9.0.1/Mac OSX 10.9 ?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19833/usage-of-assuming-for-integration/19894#19894) for how `Integrate` works with assumptions.

Comment: Great link @MichaelE2. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a stupid workaround. Anyway:

```
FindSequenceFunction@Table[Integrate[k^2 η[n, k], {k, -∞, +∞}, Assumptions -> {n == p}], {p, 5}]
(*
 π^2 #1^2 &
*)
```

Comment: Actually it's kinda useful when someone -for example- wants to see whether there's a pattern and then use proof by induction.

Comment: @Zet The problem is that it doesn't prove anything. You may get a different law for greater n, and this will overlook that fact

Answer (score 1):

Here's as close as I can get via *Mathematica*.  First, I just simplify the integrand once for all.  Having `Simplify` in the definition of a function could be really slow.  *Edit*: I added  the unsimplified versions of the OP's functions, including a substitution of `Boole` for `If`, which I omitted to include in the original answer.

```
u[n_, x_] := Boole[0 <= x <= L] Sqrt[2/L] Sin[n π x/L];
φ[n_, k_] := FourierTransform[u[n, x], x, k, FourierParameters -> {0, -1}];
η[n_, k_] := φ[n, k]\[Conjugate] φ[n, k];

integrand =
  FullSimplify[k^2 \[Eta][n, k],
               {n \[Element] Integers, n > 0, k \[Element] Reals,L > 0}]
(* -((2 k^2 L n^2 \[Pi] (-1 + (-1)^n Cos[k L]))/(k^2 L^2 - n^2 \[Pi]^2)^2) *)
```

Then, `Integrate` gets real close, if you make a substitution `k -> n k`.  Since the differential of `n k` is `n dk`, you have to multiply the `Integrate` below by `n`.

```
int = n Integrate[integrand /. k -> n k, {k, -Infinity, Infinity}];
Simplify[int, {n \[Element] Integers, n > 0}]

(* ConditionalExpression[
    (L n^2 Pi^2)/Abs[L]^3, 
    L \[Element] Reals && 3 Arg[-L^2] <= 2 \[Pi] && (Re[1/L^2] <= 0 || 1/L^2 \[NotElement] Reals)] *)

Reduce[Last[%]]
(* False *)
```

The only problem is that the condition in the `ConditionalExpression` is a contradiction.

Comment: There's something fishy going on. Sometimes I get an error that it doesn't converge, sometimes that it is undefined (e.g., when I add L>0 in the assumptions in the last Simplify[] command), and sometimes the False conditional expression you get. The result is very sensitive to the form of the integrand and my assumptions.

Comment: Yes, it is sensitive.  The denominator and numerator are zero at the same values of `k`.  Somehow, perhaps because of the way *Mathematica* manipulates the integrand, it concludes divergence even though the integrand is bounded and the integral absolutely convergent.